# Multi-line equation with split

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

I have the following problem:

[image]

Obviously I want the `=` to be aligned and I need two lines for the equation following the third `=`.

Also I'm not so sure whether I used the `\big{[}` and `\big{]}` commands correctly!?

Code so far as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\vec{V}_i &= E[\boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^*_i \boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^*_{i}' \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i]\\
&= \big{[}[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)] [\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)]' \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_{i}\big{]}
&= E[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}' - \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}' - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}'\\ + \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}' \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i]\\
&= \vec{I} \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}} + \vec{X}^*_i (\vec{X}'_i \vec{X}_i)^{-1} \vec{X}^*_{i}' \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}}.
\label{eq: covariance}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Bernard for your help.

However I do encounter another problem now aligning this equations with my previous ones.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{E}[]{}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\;\mathopen{}}
#1}
\begin{document}


I expect the abnormal returns to be jointly normally distributed with a zero conditional mean and conditional covariance matrix $\vec{V}_i$, to, as Campbell, et al show, get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E[\boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^*_i \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i] &= E[\vec{R}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i \hat{\vec{\theta}}_i \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i]\\
&= E[(\vec{R}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i \hat{\vec{\theta}}_i) - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i]\\
&= 0.
\label{eq: expectedmean}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\vec{V}_i &= \EV*{\boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^{*}_i \boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}^{*} _i}{'}\given \vec{X}^{*}_i}\\
&= \EV[\big]{[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)] [\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)]' \given \vec{X}^*_{i}}\\
&=\!\begin{multlined}[t]E\bigl[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}{'} - \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}{'}\\
+ \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} \;\big\vert\; \vec{X}^*_i\bigr]
\end{multlined}\\
&= \vec{I} \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}} + \vec{X}^*_i (\vec{X}'_i \vec{X}_i)^{-1} \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}}.
\label{eq: covariance}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Gives me the following output:[image]

Whereas I'd like to align equation (2)'s = to the right to be in line with equation (1)'s =, because I have previous equations having their = at the same horizontal measures as equation 1.

Thanks!

Comment: Comment aside, if  you load `mathdesign` with no font option, your document will use the default `Computer Modern`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `multlined` environment from `mathtools`. I also defined an `\EV` command, that works with a `given` command (following an example in the mathtools documentation). It has a simple syntax (`\EV{A \given B}` and gives a correct spacing for the `Expected Value`, and has delimiters and vertical line that adapt to the contents size in the `star` version; otherwise, it can take an optional argument (`\big, \Big`, &c.) for the size. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with line breaks, so the multilined part had to be done by hand.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{E}[]{}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\;\mathopen{}}
#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\vec{V}_i &= \EV*{\boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^{*}_i \boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}^{*} _i}{'}\given \vec{X}^{*}_i}\\
&= \EV[\big]{[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)] [\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)]' \given \vec{X}^*_{i}}\\
&=\!\begin{multlined}[t]E\bigl[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}{'} - \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}{'}\\
+ \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} \;\big\vert\; \vec{X}^*_i\bigr]
\end{multlined}\\
&= \vec{I} \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}} + \vec{X}^*_i (\vec{X}'_i \vec{X}_i)^{-1} \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}}.
\label{eq: covariance}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Insert a `\phantom` equality sign (with appropriate spacing around it - as in `{}={}`) and add `\qquad` to push that part of the equation to the right.

Here is a mock-up of what it will look like, using strutted boxes to represent your equation components:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\strutboxed}[1]{\boxed{\mathstrut\rule{#1}{0pt}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \strutboxed{2em} &= \strutboxed{15em} \\
                     &= \strutboxed{20em} \\
                     &= \strutboxed{15em} \\
                     &\phantom{{}={}} \qquad \strutboxed{10em} \\
                     &= \strutboxed{12em}.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You should also use `\bigL[` and/or `\bigR]` and friends rather than `\big`. See the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) for more information on these and other pairs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i was stopped short by the error

```
! Double superscript.
```

which was caused by several instances of this sub/superscript combination:

```
\vec{X}^*_{i}'
```

the `^*` and `'` are both superscripts, and, although this may not be immediately obvious,
tex wants to consider them as a single group. so either precede the apostrophe (prime)
by an empty group `{}` to separate it from the asterisk, or combine them as `^{*\prime}`.
(i believe the separation is what is wanted.)

also, the second line needs `\\` at the end, and the line after the third `=` needs
`&` plus some space at the beginning to indent it, as well as `{}` before the plus
to get the correct spacing for a binary operator.

here is the repaired display:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\vec{V}_i &= E[\boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^*_i
  \boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^*_{i}{}' \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i]\\
&= \big{[}[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i
  - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)]
    [\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i
  - \vec{\theta}_i)]' \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_{i}\big{]}\\
&= E[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}{}'
 - \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i
 - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}{}' - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i
 - \vec{\theta}_i) \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}{}'\\
& \qquad{}
 + \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i
 - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}{}' \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i]\\
&= \vec{I} \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}}
 + \vec{X}^*_i (\vec{X}'_i \vec{X}_i)^{-1} \vec{X}^*_{i}{}'
   \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}}.
\label{eq: covariance}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 1):

Following your question-answer, I thought "why not just use an `align` instead of two `equation`s?". I tried it out and it worked, so here it is. Note: `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` just won't work for me. I must have an outdated `mathtools`. You can put it back in. I substituted it with `E\big[` and `E[`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\providecommand\given{}
\begin{document}


I expect the abnormal returns to be jointly normally distributed with a zero conditional mean and conditional covariance matrix $\vec{V}_i$, to, as Campbell, et al show, get:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
E[\boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^*_i \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i] &= E[\vec{R}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i \hat{\vec{\theta}}_i \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i]\\
&= E[(\vec{R}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i \hat{\vec{\theta}}_i) - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) \;\;|\;\; \vec{X}^*_i]\\
&= 0.
\label{eq: expectedmean}
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
\vec{V}_i &= E[\boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}}^{*}_i \boldsymbol{\hat{\vec{\varepsilon}}^{*} _i}{'}\given \vec{X}^{*}_i]\\
&= E\big[[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)] [\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)]' \given \vec{X}^*_{i}\big]\\
&=\!
\begin{multlined}[t]
E\bigl[\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}{'} - \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} - \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}{'}\\
+ \vec{X}^*_i (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i) (\hat{\vec{\theta}}_i - \vec{\theta}_i)' \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} \;\big\vert\; \vec{X}^*_i\bigr]
\end{multlined}\\
&= \vec{I} \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}} + \vec{X}^*_i (\vec{X}'_i \vec{X}_i)^{-1} \vec{X}^*_{i}{'} \sigma^2_{\boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}^*_{i}}.
\label{eq: covariance}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The labeling also works fine.

Comment: You should add some vertical spacing between the two `split` environments — something like `\\[2ex]`. As for `mathtools, I use version 1.5, dated 2014/08/04.

Comment: Yeah it's probably a good idea. Then again, it's the OP's business, and I guess he can do that :). As for `mathtools`, I have `\ProvidesPackage{mathtools}%
  [2013/02/12 v1.13 mathematical typesetting tools]`. I will consider updating :).